convert grafana dashboard JSON data to CSV
I'm looking for a way to convert the following output from a grafana dashboard query to CSV.  I got that data with a postman request, but the same data is in the explore => data => JSON => dataframe JSON.
the header names are the values in the "fields" array.
I know it's similar to the jq recipe to "zip column headers with their rows", but I'm  looking for a CSV output with headers at the top.
the JSON file:
{
  "results": {
    "A": {
      "status": 200,
      "frames": [
        {
          "schema": {
            "name": "A",
            "refId": "A",
            "meta": {
              "typeVersion": [
                0,
                0
              ],
              "preferredVisualisationType": "table",
              "executedQueryString": "I removed the raw SQL"
            },
            "fields": [
              {
                "name": "reqTimeSec",
                "type": "time",
                "typeInfo": {
                  "frame": "time.Time"
                }
              },
              {
                "name": "statusCode",
                "type": "number",
                "typeInfo": {
                  "frame": "uint32",
                  "nullable": true
                }
              },
              {
                "name": "totalBytes",
                "type": "number",
                "typeInfo": {
                  "frame": "uint64",
                  "nullable": true
                }
              },
              {
                "name": "cliIP",
                "type": "string",
                "typeInfo": {
                  "frame": "string",
                  "nullable": true
                }
              },
              {
                "name": "country",
                "type": "string",
                "typeInfo": {
                  "frame": "string",
                  "nullable": true
                }
              },
              {
                "name": "state",
                "type": "string",
                "typeInfo": {
                  "frame": "string",
                  "nullable": true
                }
              },
              {
                "name": "city",
                "type": "string",
                "typeInfo": {
                  "frame": "string",
                  "nullable": true
                }
              },
              {
                "name": "UA",
                "type": "string",
                "typeInfo": {
                  "frame": "string",
                  "nullable": true
                }
              },
              {
                "name": "reqHost",
                "type": "string",
                "typeInfo": {
                  "frame": "string",
                  "nullable": true
                }
              },
              {
                "name": "reqPath",
                "type": "string",
                "typeInfo": {
                  "frame": "string",
                  "nullable": true
                }
              },
              {
                "name": "queryStr",
                "type": "string",
                "typeInfo": {
                  "frame": "string",
                  "nullable": true
                }
              },
              {
                "name": "referer",
                "type": "string",
                "typeInfo": {
                  "frame": "string",
                  "nullable": true
                }
              },
              {
                "name": "reqMethod",
                "type": "string",
                "typeInfo": {
                  "frame": "string",
                  "nullable": true
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          "data": {
            "values": [
              [
                1735321503269,
                1735321503292,
                1735321503361,
                1735321503381,
                1735321503522
              ],
              [
                200,
                302,
                200,
                200,
                200
              ],
              [
                14913,
                2030,
                10314,
                6598,
                61633
              ],
              [
                "1.1.1.1",
                "1.1.1.2",
                "1.1.1.3",
                "1.1.1.4",
                "1.1.1.5"
              ],
              [
                "US",
                "US",
                "US",
                "US",
                "US"
              ],
              [
                "Illinois",
                "Georgia",
                "Wisconsin",
                "Texas",
                "California"
              ],
              [
                "CHICAGO",
                "ATLANTA",
                null,
                "DALLAS",
                "LOSANGELES"
              ],
              [
                "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/131.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
                "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/131.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
                "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/131.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
                "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/131.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
                "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/131.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
              ],
              [
                "www.blahlah.com",
                "www.blahlah.com",
                "www.blahlah.com",
                "www.blahlah.com",
                "www.blahlah.com"
              ],
              [
                "/root/dir2/dir3/dir4",
                "/root/error",
                "/root/dir2/dir3/dir4",
                "/root/dir2/dir5/dir6",
                "/root/dir2/dir3/dir4"
              ],
              [
                "",
                "error_key=view.process.error",
                "",
                "",
                ""
              ],
              [
                "https://www.blahlah.com/dasfdsafadsf/?loc=en_US",
                "https://www.blahlah.com/something/login",
                "https://www.blahlah.com/dasfdsafadsf/?loc=en_US",
                "https://www.blahlah.com/dasfdsafadsf/?loc=en_US",
                "https://www.blahlah.com/dasfdsafadsf/?loc=en_US"
              ],
              [
                "POST",
                "GET",
                "POST",
                "POST",
                "POST"
              ]
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

The desired output:
reqTimeSec,statusCode,totalBytes,cliIP,country,state,city,UA,reqHost,reqPath,queryStr,referer,reqMethod
1735322367472,200,17557,1.1.1.1,US,Texas,HOUSTON,"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/131.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",www.blahlah.com,/root/dir2/dir3/dir4,loc=en_US,https://www.blahlah.com/lasso/login,GET
1735322367513,302,6972,1.1.1.2,US,Florida,MIAMI,"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/131.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/131.0.0.0",www.blahlah.com,/root/error,,https://www.blahlah.com/webqvm/?loc=en_US,POST
1735322367515,302,6972,1.1.1.3,US,Florida,MIAMI,"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/131.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/131.0.0.0",www.blahlah.com,/root/dir2/dir3/dir4,,https://www.blahlah.com/webqvm/?loc=en_US,POST
1735322367824,302,1715,1.1.1.4,US,Illinois,,"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/131.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/131.0.0.0",www.blahlah.com,/root/dir2/dir5/dir6,loc=en_US,https://www.blahlah.com/lasso/login,GET
1735322367965,302,2016,1.1.1.5,US,New%20York,NEWYORK,"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/131.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",www.blahlah.com,/root/dir2/dir3/dir4,loc=en_US,https://www.blahlah.com/lasso/login,GET


that's quite a huge json block...
